# Monads and SML modules

Tags: monads, sml

```
signature MAPPABLE = sig
  type 'a mappable
  val fmap : ('a -> 'b) -> 'a mappable -> 'b mappable
end

structure Option : MAPPABLE = struct
  type 'a mappable = 'a option
  fun fmap f v =
    case v of
      (SOME x) => SOME (f x)
    | NONE => NONE;
end

structure List : MAPPABLE = struct
  type 'a mappable = 'a list
  fun fmap f v = map f v
end


fun incByFive x = x + 5
```

Really just to have a function that does stuff with fmap

```
fun mapToPair f x =
    let val b = List.fmap f x
    in (b,b)
    end

val lst = mapToPair incByFive [1,2,3];
```

Suppose you want to make a generic implementation, that works for
all instances of MAPPABLE. The following does not work

```
fun mapToPair f x =
    let val b = MAPPABLE.fmap f x
    in (b,b)
    end
```

It seems, that SML people point to Functors, if that needs to be done.
I tried implementing one, for a generic implementation of mapToPair

```
functor FMAPFUNCTOR (structure Q : MAPPABLE)
 = struct
   fun mapToPair f x =
       let val b = Q.fmap f x
       in (b,b)
       end
end;
```

However, to use it with what in Haskell I'd call a functor
instance, I need to instantiate the functor (this reminds me of C++
templates for some reason)

```
structure MAPPABLE_TO_PAIR = FMAPFUNCTOR (structure Q = List);
val lstByPoly = MAPPABLE_TO_PAIR.mapToPair incByFive [1,2,3]
```

I would have to repeat that instantiation for every MAPPABLE
instance I want to use. I guess Haskell performs something like this,
too. Just implicitly.

Now I wonder if there is any shortcut / sugar for a better "user
experience" in SML that I have missed. Because really, it seems kind
of a lot of boilerplate in the way in order to use this in a code
base.

Answer (score 4):

> I guess Haskell performs something like this, too. Just implicitly.

The Haskell standard library defines and imports a ton of type class instances. Given a sufficient set of ML functors, their applications and their implicit compile-time imports, you could achieve something quite convenient.

But Haskell does let you automate type class instance declarations in ways that SML doesn't.

For example, `instance Foo t => Bar t where ...` is comparable to SML's higher-order functors, but in SML you explicitly have to generate a module that corresponds to `Bar t` for each concrete `Foo t`. Haskell also lets you [derive instances](https://www.haskell.org/onlinereport/derived.html) syntactically.

OCaml had [modular implicits](http://www.lpw25.net/papers/ml2014.pdf) from 2014 ([example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37694313/make-ocaml-function-polymorphic-for-int-lists-and-float-lists/37710287#37710287)), but they mainly give you syntax sugar to refer to defined functor instances, rather than generate them.

I suspect that the reason ML module systems are still more explicit than Haskell's is because of things like [overlapping instances](https://kseo.github.io/posts/2017-02-05-avoid-overlapping-instances-with-closed-type-families.html).

Andreas Rossberg contributed [1ML](https://people.mpi-sws.org/~rossberg/1ml/1ml.pdf) in 2014 in which modules are first-class citizens. That means a function could take a module as an argument, e.g. like [this](https://github.com/rossberg/1ml/blob/master/talk.1ml#L93-L105):

```
;; Higher-kinded polymorphism

type MONAD (m : type => type) =
{
  return 'a : a -> m a;
  bind 'a 'b : m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b;
};

map 'a 'b (m : type => type) (M : MONAD m) (f : a -> b) mx =
  M.bind mx (fun x => M.return (f x));

do map :
  'a => 'b => (m : type => type) => (M : MONAD m) => (a -> b) -> m a -> m b;
```

This is still research-y in the sense that the compiler has "TOY" in its name, but it'd be an example of an ML (although not Standard ML) that does something comparably generic with modules.